# How do i parse a text file and use the file input in constructors to create a container of objects

Tags: c++, oop

I have a program that reads a text file line by line for names, and stores those names as objects using a constructor. The constructor is being used to make a vector of all the names. However, my problem is that i need my names to have attributes tied to them, i have the constructor for the attributes but i have no clue how to parse the text file to separate the names from the attributes, and then how to store the attributes with the names.

My code works for just names in the file, and i cannot simply use a delimiter in this case since i need to look for "Name" then attribute attribute attribute.

Example:

"Baron Samedi" Mage Magical Ranged

the name needs to be stored without the quotes included and then the attributes need to be constructed in a container that corresponds to the names, so that when i call .getAttackType for a specific name (object) it will return the appropriate type.

````
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>


enum class AttackType {
    MELEE,
    RANGE
};

enum class DamageType {
    MAGICAL,
    PHYSICAL
};

enum class AbilityType {
    Mage,
    Guardian,
    Warrior,
    Hunter,
    Assassin
};

struct EntityAttributes {

    AttackType attackType;
    DamageType damageType;
    AbilityType abilityType;
};

class Entity {
private:
    std::string name_;
    EntityAttributes attribs_;

public:
    Entity() = default;
    explicit Entity(const std::string& name) :
        name_(name)
    {}
    Entity(const std::string& name, EntityAttributes attribs) :
        name_(name),
        attribs_(attribs)
    {}

    void assignAttributes(EntityAttributes attribs) {
        attribs_ = attribs;
    }

    std::string getName() const { return name_; }

    AbilityType getClassType() const { return attribs_.abilityType; }
    AttackType getAttackType() const { return attribs_.attackType; }
    DamageType getDamageType() const { return attribs_.damageType; }
};

void getAllLinesFromFile(const char* filename, std::vector<std::string>& output) {
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file) 
    {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "failed to open file " << filename << '\n';
        throw std::runtime_error(stream.str());
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(file, line)) {
        if (line.size() > 0)
            output.push_back(line);
    }
    file.close();
}

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    try {
        // This will store all of the names in from the text file.
        std::vector<std::string> names;
        getAllLinesFromFile("Names.txt", names);

        // This will give us a container of all of our entities with a provided name
        // after this container is filled you can go back later and add the addition
        // properties, or if you read the properties in from a file as well you can use
        // the other Entity constructor to generate all of them with their names and properties
        std::vector<Entity> entities;
        for (auto& n : names) {
            Entity e(n);
            entities.push_back(e);
        }

        // Check array of Entities
        std::cout << "There are " << entities.size() << " entities\n";
        for (auto& e : entities) {
            std::cout << e.getName() << '\n';
        }
}
    catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    system("pause");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}```
````

Comment: I don't entirely understand your question, but you probably need to write some code that breaks the line up into pieces. Text parsing is an important skill in coding, and you'll end up writing tons and tons of text parsing routines if you become a programmer. I did a Google for "text parsing examples in c" and found a number of good examples of how to start. What I would do is start a NEW program that does nothing but helps you learn to parse the string, then incorporate what you know into your existing program.

Comment: @JosephLarson I helped him get this far from his initial question. Yes string parsing is a challenge but it is also a near must needed to know skill in programming.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Absolutely. IMHO, for whatever it's worth, trying to get lengthy tutorials from Stack Overflow is problematic, but I offered a Google search that nets some good tutorials to try. Learning to program is hard. It takes dedication. But the tools available today are SO much better than the tools when I learned back in the 70s. If we learned then, it should be easier now.

Comment: @JosephLarson So true. I first started learning C++ in the early 2000s when the internet was still considered young and most people didn't even have pcs and the majority of pcs that were out there were using either Windows 98, 2000 or XP if they were on a Windows platform. Most of the content that I had found back then were all text base sites and many of them were in the form of ftp sites unlike the interactive sites today. There was no Youtube with video tutorials, just a bunch of text and links with some graphics. And dial up was slow.

Comment: The thingies you want to read are not lines of text but `Entity`s. Overload `operator<<(std::istream &is, Entity &entity)` for Entity and just do `std::vector<Entity> entities{ std::istream_iterator<Entity>{ input_file }, std::istream_iterator<Entity>{} };`

Comment: It all depends on your file structure.

Comment: Yeah thank you, @FrancisCugler i was able to build a TON of the minigame for the past few hours but unfortunately i'm stuck again because i don't know to to parse that file. I think i may just create an array of the data with indices matching the container because i cant figure it out and i need those attributes for the rest of the minigame.

Comment: I watched some videos but nothing explained how to specifically take the string in the quotes, i thought about using a sentinel but i couldn't get that working either. Thank you for the help. I think i'm just going to hard code an array of every attribute then search the array for the string.

Comment: @Zixxle gah, i gave you the solution to your "problem" above. and please stop watching youtube videos titled "tutorials". Those are made by n00bs and full of bs.

Comment: @Swordfish I see that but i don't see how that will separate the names from the attributes. The big problem here is that some of the names have spaces in them such as Ah Muzen Cab. I will try it and see if it accomplishes what im after, thank you as well.

Comment: @Swordfish true unless the person is Jason Turner, Bo Qian or Bisqwit! I have found those three to actually be really good at their craft.

Comment: I would refrain from "hardcoding data". This tends to lead to bad practices, especially later on when it is a requirement to be able to parse large data sets from files... Also if you read contents in from a file all in one shot and store it into some buffer to be parsed later, close the file and be done with it, the parsing part is a challenge yes, but once you have your parser working, you'll be grateful you implemented it. Like I said, it will greatly reduce your compile and build times every time you change an attribute. It is easier to find bugs, etc.

Comment: @FrancisCugler *Jason Turner, Bo Qian or Bisqwit* – i don't anyone of these.

Comment: @Swordfish Well at different times they have actually helped me understand something about programming in general specifically in c++. So I wouldn't say that All Youtube videos are by noobs. Yes many are but there are some good ones out there.

Comment: @FrancisCugler I specifically said youtube videos with "Tutorial" in the title ...

Comment: *The big problem here is that some of the names have spaces in them such as Ah Muzen Cab. I will try it and see if it accomplishes what im after, thank you as well.* – use `std::istream::ignore()` ... see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your original file format:

```
#include <string>       // std::string
#include <vector>       // std::vector<>
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout, std::cerr
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream
#include <ctime>        // std::time()
#include <cstdlib>      // std::rand(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <iterator>     // std::istream_iterator<>
#include <limits>       // std::numeric_limits<>
#include <algorithm>    // std::find()

char const *AbilityTypeStrings[]{ "Mage", "Guardian", "Warrior", "Hunter", "Assassin" };
enum class AbilityType {
    Mage,
    Guardian,
    Warrior,
    Hunter,
    Assassin
};

char const *DamageTypeStrings[]{ "Magical", "Physical" };
enum class DamageType {
    MAGICAL,
    PHYSICAL
};

char const *AttackTypeStrings[]{ "Melee", "Range" };
enum class AttackType {
    MELEE,
    RANGE
};

struct EntityAttributes {
    AttackType attackType;
    DamageType damageType;
    AbilityType abilityType;
};

class Entity {
    std::string name;
    EntityAttributes attributes;

public:
    Entity(std::string const &name = {}, EntityAttributes const &attributes = {}) :
        name(name),
        attributes(attributes)
    {}

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Entity &entity)
    {
        // ignore everything up to the first '"'.
        is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\"');

        // try to read the entities name
        std::string name;
        if (!std::getline(is, name, '\"')) {
            return is;
        }

        // try to read its abilities
        std::string abilities;
        if (!(is >> abilities)) {
            return is;
        }

        EntityAttributes attributes{};
        auto ability_type{ std::find(std::begin(AbilityTypeStrings), std::end(AbilityTypeStrings), abilities) };

        if (ability_type == std::end(AbilityTypeStrings)) {
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            return is;
        }

        attributes.abilityType = static_cast<AbilityType>(ability_type - std::begin(AbilityTypeStrings));

        std::string damage;
        if (!(is >> damage)) {
            return is;
        }

        auto damage_type{ std::find(std::begin(DamageTypeStrings), std::end(DamageTypeStrings), damage) };

        if (damage_type == std::end(DamageTypeStrings)) {
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            return is;
        }

        attributes.damageType = static_cast<DamageType>(damage_type - std::begin(DamageTypeStrings));

        std::string attack;
        if (!(is >> attack)) {
            return is;
        }

        auto attack_type{ std::find(std::begin(AttackTypeStrings), std::end(AttackTypeStrings), attack) };

        if (attack_type == std::end(AttackTypeStrings)) {
            is.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
            return is;
        }

        attributes.attackType = static_cast<AttackType>(attack_type - std::begin(AttackTypeStrings));


        entity.name = name;
        entity.attributes = attributes;

        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Entity const &entity)
    {
        os << '\"' << entity.name << "\"\n" << DamageTypeStrings[static_cast<std::size_t>(entity.attributes.damageType)] << '\n'
           << AbilityTypeStrings[static_cast<std::size_t>(entity.attributes.abilityType)] << '\n'
           << AttackTypeStrings[static_cast<std::size_t>(entity.attributes.attackType)] << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned>(std::time(nullptr)));  // why do you include <random> when
                                                            // you're using the old old C stuff?
    char const *filename{ "test.txt" };
    std::ifstream is{ filename };
    if (!is.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open \"" << filename << "\" for reading :(\n\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    std::vector<Entity> entities{ std::istream_iterator<Entity>{ is }, std::istream_iterator<Entity>{} };

    for (auto const &e : entities)
        std::cout << e << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks, i got it working with what i had, you rock though. But i do have a weird bug, is it possible that i could email you my code and you see whats going on? My email is adinbrimberry@gmail.com if you want to shoot me an email ill send the code. Everything works but theres a strange bug with the output.

Comment: @Zixxle if you have another question please ask another question. ^^

Answer (score 0):

How you parse your data all depends on your file structure and remember you can structure your file to your own specific format as long as you stay consistent with your convention.

You can do it as you attempted:

```
SingleWordName Class DamageType AttackType
"Multiple Word Name" Class DamageType AttackType
```

Then you would have to parse each line (string) of text individually but you could also make it simpler by changing the structure of your text file. If you know that there is going be a similar pattern throughout that doesn't change than something like this might make it easier for your.

```
SingleWordName or Multiple Word Name
AbilityType
AttackType
DamageType

NextName
AbilityType
AttackType
DamageType
```

Then if you structured it this way you know that each line contains a string, the first line in a set would be the name variable to your Entity class, and the next three would fill the Attributes Structure within that class. Then a blank line that can be ignored. This blank line is only for visual reading references for the human reader to easily distinguish one entity to the next.

You could even structure your file like this:

```
Entity Name Single Or Multiple Words
AbilityType AttackType DamageType

Next Entity
AbilityType AttackType DamageType
```

This kind of structure would take the first line of text or string and sets the name of the entity, then the second line contains all of the fields for the Attributes structure.
This case would work easily enough if all of your Attributes are all Single Words Only. If You have attributes that are multiple words and don't like the idea of enclosing them in quotes, brackets, braces, etc. you could just use an underscore between each word such as:

```
Baron_Samedi
```

Then once you have this word, you can look for any `_` in that word and remove it from the string and replace it with a `' '`.

There are multiple ways to parse string data, and it all depends on two major things: first your data or class structures and second your file structure that you are using to represent that data structure. Once you have these two in place you have your foundation, then it is a matter of using that information and building your parsing function from it.

---

**Edit -** follow up on the OPs comment about the confusion of parsing a string between quotes:

If you have a string in quotes `" "`; The issue here is you have to do more than one search on that string for the single character `"` and you need to keep an index of where you found the first_occurence_of `"` as well as the next_occurence_of `"`. After finding the first occurrence and saving its index location you then have to iterate through that sequence of characters like an array until you find the next `"` and again you will need to save that index location as well. Then you have to get the difference between the two.

As for a simple example we will use `"Hello"` with the quotes being our string that has 7 total characters. The first `"` is at index `0` and the next is at index `6`. You then would need the substring [(first+1), (next-1)] from this original string.

```
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6]
["][H][e][l][l][o]["]
```

As you can see above the first `"` is at index `0` and the next is at index `6`. The total length of the string is 7. We can use this information and the provided string functions from the stl to construct a substring from this original string. But we have to search the string from beginning to end to find both locations of our beginning and ending delimiters.

```
// Pseudo Code
substring = [(original.firstIndexFound(") + 1) to (original.nextIndexFound(")-1)];
// Where the [] indicates inclusive at that position...
substring = [(0+1) to (6-1)] = [1,2,3,4,5]
// broken down into individual array indices..
substring[0] = original[1]
substring[1] = original[2]
substring[2] = original[3]
substring[3] = original[4]
substring[4] = original[5] 

// Visual Translation:

// Original:
[0][1][2][3][4][5][6]
["][H][e][l][l][o]["]

// Sub
[0][1][2][3][4]
[H][e][l][l][o]
```

This will still work if there are spaces between words because the function that you call with your delimiter is not looking for a , but a `"` or any other character that you are determining to be your delimiter.

---

Here is a simple program to demonstrate parsing a string between `" "`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string str = { "\"Hello\"" }; // need the \" for quote in the string
    std::cout << "Original String = " << str << '\n';

    size_t first = str.find_first_of('"');
    size_t next = str.find_first_of('"', first + 1);
    std::cout << "First index at: " << first << "\nNext index at: " << next << '\n';

    std::string sub = str.substr(first + 1, next - 1);
    std::cout << "Substring = " << sub << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

*-Output-*

```
Original String = "Hello"
First index at: 0
Next index at: 6
Substring = Hello
```

*-Note-*

> There is no sanity check in the above to determine if there was no `"` character in the string at all. This is easy enough to do, all you have to do is check first if the index or iterator to the string is not at the end position, if it is at the end position then just return back the original string, otherwise just perform the above calculations without any changes.

Comment: Okay actually the underscore format makes way more sense. Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah it is a simple search for _ and replace with ' '.

Comment: There are many ways and many different tricks into parsing data from files. Text is usually harder. Binary is easier, however with binary you have to know the exact size in bytes and count of data you are pulling in from the binary file and you have to know the file structure completely. Binary parsing is a bit easier, but to structure your file is a bit harder because you would need a very good Hex Editor to open and read a binary file, and to test the contents of the file to make sure that the reading and writing to a binary file is done correctly.

Comment: Yeah that hugely simplified the problem in my head, the quotes was really throwing me off this makes much more sense. I can definitely manage that. You're incredible. Thank you again.

Comment: I'll edit the above answer to reflect on the idea of parsing a string between two identical delimiters...

Comment: @Zixxle I finished with my edit on basic string parsing with multiple delimiters; hope this helps.

Comment: @Zixxle I even added a small sample program explaining how to extract a sub string between 2 characters.

Comment: IMHO there is no need for `find()` when there is `getline()` that accepts a delimiter.

Comment: Awesome, i figured everything out now, im able to get all of the attributes successfully,. I ran into another problem when trying to use conditon to check if the return type matched AbilityType::Mage but i realized its an enumeration so i static cast the returned enum as int and then the comparison works just fine. Thank you!